How to detect in Android when a dialog is shown from an SDK without host app interaction?
I'm developing an SDK, and I need to detect when a dialog is shown within the host app, but I don't want to rely on explicit triggers from the host app.
The host app creates a dialog like this:
private fun createAlertDialog() {
    val dialog: AlertDialog

    val input = EditText(this).apply {
        layoutParams = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
        )
        inputType = InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD or InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT
        filters = arrayOf(InputFilter.LengthFilter(15))
        id = R.id.edit_text_dialog
    }

    val ll = LinearLayout(this).apply {
        orientation = LinearLayout.VERTICAL
        addView(input)
    }

    val builder: AlertDialog.Builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        .setCancelable(false)
        .setTitle("Dialog Title")
        .setMessage("Dialog Message")
        .setView(ll)
        .setOnKeyListener { dialog, keyCode, event ->
            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
                dialog.dismiss()
                true
            } else {
                false
            }
        }
        .setPositiveButton("Ok") { _, _ -> }

    dialog = builder.create()
    dialog.window?.setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE)
    dialog.show()
    dialog.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE).id = R.id.button_dialog
}

I want to detect the dialog being shown from my SDK without the host app explicitly calling any SDK methods. I thought about using View.addOnLayoutChangeListener on the activity's root view. Here is what I have tried so far and it's doesn't work:
// Inside my SDK code
fun observeDialogShowing(activity: Activity) {
    val rootView = activity.window.decorView.rootView

    rootView.addOnLayoutChangeListener(object : View.OnLayoutChangeListener {
        override fun onLayoutChange(
            v: View?,
            left: Int,
            top: Int,
            right: Int,
            bottom: Int,
            oldLeft: Int,
            oldTop: Int,
            oldRight: Int,
            oldBottom: Int
        ) {
            // Check if the dialog view is now visible
            Log.d("MainActivity2", "onLayoutChange")
        }
    })
}


I tried to using the ActivityLifecycleCallbacks interface and check if a dialog is shown in the onActivityResumed method and also using the ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener interface.
Both options don't work.
My question is: How can I detect when a dialog is shown in an Android app from my SDK without requiring explicit triggers from the host app?

Not possible.  There is no such API.  Not to mention that a dialog doesn't have to be the actual Dialog class-  a Dialog can be just a view popped over the other views (and sometimes that's the right way to build it).  Nor would there be any way to know that it's the right dialog (they could have a dozen in their app, would you really want to do that to any of them)?
